# Quota for samba storage

Tags: samba, cifs, hetzner

I have a Hetzner StorageBox and I want to use it for my users. I can access it using FTP/FTPS, SFTP/SCP, Rsync/BorgBackup, SMB/CIFS, and HTTPS/WebDAV.

I've successfully mounted it with CIFS on my Ubuntu server and now I need to limit disk space for each user. Users should be able to access their directories on the StorageBox using FTP and SMB.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? I believe CIFS may not support Linux quotas.

Comment: Have you done `man smbquota`?

Answer (score 0):

With FTP you can system level quotas using the `quota` tool and use samba and configure samba to  configure quotas in the Samba configuration file (smb.conf) using the `disk quota` command and related options.